# Cannot Convert From ModelA to ModelB Entity Framework error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm just getting the hang of EF but i have just run into an issue and i wonder if someone could help:

I have two Models like this:

```
public class Car
{

  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Manufacturer {get; set;}
  public string City {get;set;}

}

    public class CarInfo
    {

      public int Id {get; set;}
      public int CarId {get; set;}
      public string  Colour {get;set;}
      public string Variant {get;set;}
      public virtual Car Car {get;set;}

    }
```

I am  inserting data in the car Table like this:

```
int id = 0;
var _car = new Car()
{
  Manufacturer = "BMW",
  City = "London"
};
db.Add(_car);
db.SaveChanges();
id = _car.Id;
```

then now I am trying to save data into the CarInfo table like this:

```
 CarContext db = new CarContext();
var _carInfo = new CarInfo()
{
 CarId = id,
 Colour = "Blue",
 Variant = "Sport"
};
db.Add(_carInfo) //I'm getting an error here (red line under code) error: Cannot Convert from CarInfo to Car.
```

What is it that i'm missing out? or is this even possible to achieve using Entity Framework?

Comment: For `db.add(_carInfo)` please show us how you defined and populated `db`.

Comment: What is the `db` variable?  Seems strange that (1) you would call `SaveChanges()` on the same object to which you add a record; and (2) the `add()` method is lowercase.  What sort of custom thing have you created and how are you supposed to use it?

Comment: What is the context of `db`?

Comment: I have edited my question .. db is my connection string to the database

Comment: @1future: Where is `CarContext` defined?  Specifically what is the definition of that `.Add()` method?  It's highly unusual for a data context to itself have such a method.

Comment: I am an idiot sorry ! i was references a wrong table in the db set; Thank you

Comment: In your car info, you have public virtual Car Car. I think it should be public virtual Car car

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please show me your DbSet properties in your CarContext class, it should be

```
public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
public DbSet<CarInfo> CarInfos { get; set;}
```

And the EF Add method should be something like:

```
db.Cars.Add(_car);
```

and

```
db.CarInfos.Add(_carInfo);
```

Comment: Yes you are right! i am stupid .. i was referencing a wrong table.